# Sobolev space $H^s(Q)$ is Hilbert

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

For $Q=[-\pi,\pi)$ and $s\geq 0$, define the Sobolev space
\begin{equation}
H^s(Q):=\{f\in L^2(Q):\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(1+k^2)^s|\hat f(k)|^2<+\infty\}
\end{equation}

1. Prove that $H^s(Q)$ is a Hilbert with respect to the inner product
   \begin{equation}
   (f,g)_s:=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(1+k^2)^s\hat{f}(k)\overline{\hat{g}(k)}
   \end{equation}

**My idea:**

Let $\{f_j\}\subset H^s(Q)$ a Cauchy sequence, in particular the sequence is Cauchy in $L^2(Q)$ and then $\exists f\in L^2(Q)$ such that $||f_j-f||_{L^2}\rightarrow 0$ for $j\rightarrow +\infty$. I have to prove that $f\in H^s(Q)$.

I know that:
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(k)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_Qf(x)e^{-ikx}dx
\end{equation}
so:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(1+k^2)^s|\hat{f}(k)|^2\leq\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}(1+k^2)^s|\frac{1}{\pi}\liminf_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\hat{f_n}(k)|^2
\end{equation}
but now I have no ideas to continue.

Comment: Instead of using the $L^2$ limit, note that since $\sum (1+k^2)|\widehat {f_n-f_m}(s)|$ is going to zero, this gives rise to a Cauchy sequence (in $n$) which is convergent for each $k$. Use these limits to create a function $f$. Now prove that $f \in \mathbb H^s$ by actually proposing the derivatives of $f$ (Suppose $f$ is given by a convergent Fourier series, what would it be? Now show that sum is uniformly convergent). In this manner, you will be able to show that $f \in H^s$. Then use convergence of Fourier coefficients to argue $f_n \to f$ in $H^s$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг How can I create the function f?

Comment: You create the function $f$, by creating the Fourier coefficients of $f$, and then forming $f$ as a Fourier series. The Fourier coefficients of $f$ will be given by the limits of the Fourier coefficients of $f_n$ as $n \to \infty$, which will exist because of the Cauchy condition on $f_n$.